# What kind of clause?

Tags: clauses

The price of the stock fell more than $10 to end the day about $18, **the first time stock prices have ever fell below $20**.

What kind of clause is the one marked in bold? Can we separate these two clauses just by using a comma?

Comment: It's not a clause but a noun phrase with the clause "stock prices have ever fallen" serving as complement of the noun "time".

Comment: I'd say it could also be viewed as a relative clause (with missing _when_) modifying _time_. To view it as a complement, _time_ would have to be interpreted as a picture noun, describing a reported event, which is also quite reasonable.

Comment: @BillJ: I don't get it - you mean a phrase ("the first time stock prices have ever fell below $20") and inside this phrase is a clause ("stock prices have ever fallen")? What would this whole phrase modify within the independent clause? Without thinking about grammar rules, when I read this sentence, it seems for me that "the first time stock prices have ever fell below $20" modifies the whole first clause, but I can not find any grammar rule for that.

Comment: @John Lawler: Does a when-relative clause not describe the time when an action happens, or modifies a noun (e.g. "the summer when ...")? But, I think "the first time stock prices have ever fell below $20" is more like a result of the first clause. My interpretation: "Since Stock X fell to $18, it is now the first time any stock fell below $20." What do you think about this?

Comment: @LeeMee322 Yes, that is the structure. No, the NP (noun phrase) doesn't modify the preceding clause. The comma marks the NP as a supplement, a loosely attached expression providing supplementary non-integrated content. Although there is a semantic relationship between the clause and the supplement, the latter is syntactically quite separate.

Comment: @LeeMee322 Incidentally, I take the element "stock prices (that) have ever fell below $20" to be a declarative content clause (a _that_ clause) hence my analysis of it as a complement -- most _that_ clauses are complements.